# How can I change the precision of a field used in a field collection or content type?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, database

I have a decimal field (ie field_testing) with precision = 10 and scale = 8.  I need to change the precision to 11.  I was planning on writing a migration script that does the following:

- Update field_config row with field_name = 'field_testing' -- set the 'precision' field to 11.
- Alter the field_testing table structure to adjust the precision of the 'field_testing_value' field to 11.

Few questions related to this:

1. Given that I run this while in maintenance mode, is this safe to do?
2. Is there anything else I need to do?  The default values is and will still be blank, so changes need to go into field_config_instance, I think.

Thanks,
Larry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larry,
On the Drupal side, those are the only changes you need to make, the field_config_instance table doesn't track the data specifications. Just don't forget to clear the cache_field table, and the MySQL tables themselves too.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the field data and field data revisions tables does not appear to be all that is needed.

I went through this and ran `drush cc all` when I go to:

> /admin/structure/types/manage/company/fields/field_[rest of field
>   name]

I am presented with the old precision value still. It appears **field_config** also needs to be updated but I am not sure how to best change the data column. This appears to be a better solution which I have not implemented yet.

[trying to change field type through sql: Notice: Undefined index: precision in number_field_schema()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2254843)